Create a gimbal like structure with Technic gears
I would like to attach a sensor to a plate, and tilt that plate slightly in the XY direction respectively, without moving the plate itself.
Similar to this (force feedback joystick concept) like this one:

But not for force feedback, just for using two servos to adjust the plate's left/right (X) and front/back (Y) direction.

Do you want to translate the plate, or do you want to tilt the plate?

I believe the answer to that would be Tilt.

I immediately had to think of the Lego Ideas 21305 Maze set. It has this kind of setup built into it, with two knobs to control the bi-axial tilt of the upper plate.

Are you working under any size constraints (height, width) ? And how many degrees of tilt would you need in each direction ?

@SanderDeDycker yes, size constraints are around 1 sq inch for a quadric plate that should be able to tilt around 10 degrees in each direction (for a total of around 20 degrees in x tilt direction and the same for y, if that makes sense)

The link looks like it would be roughly the solution, but looking for a minimal solution for a plate size of roughly 1x1 inches

@user3607022 can you please tell your size constraints in LEGO dimensions - studs.

Hmmm, perhaps 5

@user3607022 You might wanna read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles and use "roll" and "pitch" instead of "front/back" and "left/right".

Ok yeah so it'd be Pitch and Yaw then.

Check out the instructions (around steps 10-11) of 8855 Prop Plane. This model has a control stick that can tilt around two perpendicular axles:

